# Designing a universal CAN bus interface

Tags: can

I'm tasked to work for several car manufacturers and would like a system that can work with 'every' car.
For example, I bought the peak system CAN Bus usb, and tried it for Kia e Niro and it didn't get any message, I don't know why still.
Is it possible to have a standard CAN system that can work with every car ?

Comment: It's because te vehicle CAN bus has different voltage levels (physical layer)  than those industrial CAN bus.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Thanks so much for that hint, do you know a solution for that ?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič isn't  can  a differential bus and you can operate them on two different voltages like that ?

Comment: What does "work with every car" mean? The OBD port or something else? If so, these things most likely already exist, don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @Lundin You always help me, thanks. The normal OBDII bus with Kia netro, didn't work, I just connected the cable and tried to get messages, but nothing I get. The problem right now I would like to work on a car but most OBD CAN Bus usbs don't have APIs that I can interface with, most of them use bluetooth connected to app, or save to disk the data